# How to make your own data type like int, long in C?

Tags: c, data-structures, custom-data-type

I'm beginner in `c` and I want to create my own data type which I can use like `int` but to store bigger numbers. For example, how can I allocate memory for this data type with malloc?

Comment: On which operating system? With which compiler?

Comment: You can't just store gigantic numbers and use them like an `int`. If you want to operate on a number larger than the biggest primitive type the compiler handles (e.g. a `long long` [are those in C?]) then you need to use a library or write some custom code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read some [C programming](http://www.cprogramming.com/) book about `struct`-ures, `union`-s, pointers, and data types. Read more about [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation)

To deal with big numbers, you'll better use some [bignum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) (a.k.a. arbitrary-precision arithmetic) library, such as [GMPlib](https://gmplib.org/). So your question becomes implementation and operating system specific.

<sup>Notice that bignum arithmetic involves tricky and difficult algorithms (better than naive approaches).</sup>

You should become more fluent about programming in C before using it (GMPlib). Be afraid of [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and [memory leaks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).